# ASP MVC submit list not mapping all values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-submit

I have a table where the user can add a entry and once the user is done they they can add another.

After they added a entry they can remove it again. This is where the problem happens. Here is an example

ACTION:

```
Public ActionResult Submit(List<String> Names)
{
   //DO STUFF
}
```

When they add a entry it will grab the index of the previous entry and add a hidden field for it, so at the end it will look something like this:

HTML:

```
 <input type="hidden" name='Names[0]' value='John'/>
 <input type='hidden' name='Names[1]' value='Peter' />
 <input type='hidden' name='Names[2]  value='David' />
```

When I submit this it will map all the names correcty. The problem is that the user can remove one of the names after they added it before the submit. If they remove the input with the value 'Peter' the html will look like this

HTML AFTER REMOVE:

```
 <input type="hidden" name='Names[0]' value='John'/>
 <input type='hidden' name='Names[2]  value='David' />
```

When this gets submitted, only the input with the value 'John', will get mapped.

Does anyone know how to fix this without coding a jquery function that will redo all the indexes in the html? I'm looking for a solution that I can add server side for the bindings, a override or something. The reason I don't want to do it with jquery is because I have multiple pages that has such functionality, and doing it for each page will be quite time time consuming.

********EDIT****************

The code above are just an example, one of my models that I try to bind look like the following:

```
public class Product {
   public string Code {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
   public decimal Price {get;set;}

}
```

And then obviously in my Action

```
public ActionResult Submit(List<namespace.Product> Products)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple pages that have such fonctionality, isn't it possible to reuse it instead of implementing it for each page ? You may be able to do it with one jQuery function applied to all your pages. Anyway, if you want to do it using a controller, you put your hidden list in a partial view that get refreshed every time an entry is added or removed, in order to update your indexes each time.

Comment: Read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) Phil Haack's article about how the `DefaultModelBinder` with collections works, especially **Non-Sequential Indices** chapter.

Comment: @RédaMattar, the problem is that the models is different on all of the pages.

Comment: @Zabavsky, thank you, that looks exactly like what I'm looking for, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Zabavsky comment, I found the solution I was looking for.

I used non-sequential indices.

Here is an example:

Action:

```
 public ActionResult Create(List<namespace.Product> Products)
 {
    //do stuff
 }
```

Model:

```
public class Product {
   public string Code {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
   public decimal Price {get;set;}

}
```

In my form the html will look like the following:

```
<input type='hidden' name='Products.Index' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[1].Code' value='xyz' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[1].Name' value='Shirt' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[1].Quantity' value='5'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[1].Price' value='50'/>

<input type='hidden' name='Products.Index' value='7'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[7].Code' value='zxy' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[7].Name' value='Pants' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[7].Quantity' value='8'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[7].Price' value='70'/>

<input type='hidden' name='Products.Index' value='foo'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[foo].Code' value='1234' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[foo].Name' value='Shoes' />
<input type='hidden' name='Products[foo].Quantity' value='2'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Products[foo].Price' value='100'/>
```

All these will bind correctly. All that I had to add was the:

```
<input type='hidden' name='Products.Index' value='1'/>
```

All the index values just needs to be unique for this to work, so with just a few lines of jquery I was able to achieve this.

More information can be found here: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try update the model with Ajax jQuery, that could be more eassier.

you can add a input button like:

```
<input type="button" value="Save/Update" id="saveUpdate" />
//Other HtmlCode

//Now script code
<script>
$(function(){

 $("#saveUpdate").click(function({
      $.ajax({
         url: '/myController/GetDataForInvoiceNumber',
         type: 'POST',
         data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
         },
         success: function (result) {
            CheckIfInvoiceFound(result);
         },
         async: true,
         processData: false
      });

 });

});
</script>

//Contoller
Public ActionResult Submit(Products requestData)
{
   //DO STUFF
}
```

That could works

Comment: This is a viable solution, but I want to submit everything at once with other information also so that is why I didn't solve it using ajax. I would had to make big changes to the system flow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an index to submit a list to the controller.

```
Public ActionResult Submit(string[] Names)
{
   //DO STUFF
}
```

Then just change `Names[]` to just `Names` and it will still map to the `Names` parameter even if you remove items.

```
<input type="hidden" name='Names' value='John'/>
<input type='hidden' name='Names`  values='David' />
```

Comment: sorry my models are a bit more complex than in my example. One of my actions take a list of a model that has multiple parameters. I have a list of my Product Model, and that models contains Name, Quantity and Price. So using your method won't work I believe. Sorry I should have made better example

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured this out a long time ago but it looks like you have a typo. Your example is using "values" instead of "value" for the second row
  values='David' />